# MYSQL connection error using service name as user host

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a couple of containers which need to connect to a mysql container. For this example I will use my `webapi` container. Currently I am able to do this if my "test" user `host` is set to the IP (172.18.0.4) of the container in the mysql user table.

My understanding is that I can use the service name from the docker-compose file since they will be on the same network, thus not relying on an IP. Although when I change the `host` of my "test" user to the service name of the container e.g. `webapi`. I get thrown a mysql error.

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'172.18.0.4' (using password: YES)`

My docker-compose file is as

```
version: '2.3'
services:
webapp:
  image: webapp:0.3
  networks:
    - frontend
  depends_on:
    - database
webapi:
  image: webapi:0.2
  networks:
    - frontend
  depends_on:
    - database
database:
  image: database:0.1
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
  volumes:
    - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  frontend:
    external: true
  backend:
    external: true
volumes:
  mysql-data:
   external:
    name: mysql-data
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or is my understanding of being able to use the service name as the MYSQL user `host` incorrect?

The database image is built from the official MariaDB dockerfile.

Comment: Error not connected with Docker. May be you wrote wrong password, or you can not access to database using that user from that host (as default only 127.0.0.1 allowed). You can try to change it to 127.*.*.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this but forgot to reply back. Interestingly the dockerfile sets the *skip-name-resolve* which disables DNS host name lookup.

I found this a bit odd as docker pushes the developer into using the container names as the DNS records...

So if you come across this issue, remove the line where it echo's it into the .cnf file near the bottom of the Dockerfile.

Comment: I've been running into a similar issue with LXD as I've forgotten that LXD's default bridges (lxdbr0 etc) need a .lxd domain specifier to resolve local hostnames correctly. While 'user'@'host.lxd' works, 'user'@'host' does not. I'm leaving this comment for others who might be running into this issue with LXC/LXD.